# What happens if I don't bury corpses?

Tags: civ-clicker

So a wolf attacked and I have a few dead people lying around. While I do have a cleric, I don't have a graveyard so they aren't getting buried. I don't really feel like spending resources on a graveyard at the moment, but what happens if I just leave rotting corpses lying around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If left unburied, your other workers can get sick. They will need to be healed by an apothecary with herbs to survive.

Source: http://civ-clicker.wikia.com/wiki/Corpses